# Change Entity assert constrains dynamically without FormType

Tags: php, symfony, validation, entity

So the problem is like this:

I am trying to save some data from API and I need to validate them with Symfony validation ex:

```
private $id;

    /**
     * @var
     * @Assert\Length(max="255")
     * @CustomAssert\OrderExternalCode()
     * @CustomAssert\OrderShipNoExternalCode()
     */
    private $code;

    private $someId;

    /**
     * @var
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Length(max="255")
     */
    private $number;
```

this works well but now I need to add some Assert Constrains dynamically from the controller and that is where I am stuck!

Does anyone knows how to do that or any suggestion that might help?

Currently I did an extra constraint which does extra query in the DB and I don't want to do that and I am not using FormType.

Comment: You could use the Symfony Validator service in your controller : https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html

Comment: I am doing that, but I need to add an extra constraint based on some condition for a specific field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I wanted to dynamically validate the request data based on a condition in the controller.

I specified an extra group for that in the entity like so:

```
    /**
      * @var
      * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"extra_check"})
      * @Assert\Length(max="255")
      */
     private $externalId;
```

Then in the controller I just did the condition to validate with the extra group or not.

```
$groups = $order->getExternalCode() != null ? ['Default'] : ['Default', 'extra_check'];
$this->validateRequest($request, null, $groups);
```

The Default group is the one without group specified and the other one is the group I specified in the field

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`groups`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/groups.html) and use (or leave out) the extra group you're talking about.

Comment: Yes that's how I did it

Answer (score 0):

Using the **CallbackConstraint** should help I think, in your case :

```php
use My\Custom\MyConstraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Context\ExecutionContextInterface;

// This is not tested !
class MyEntity
{
    /**
     * @Assert\Callback()
     */
    public function validateSomeId(ExecutionContextInterface $context)
    {
        $constraint = new MyConstraint(['code' => $this->code]);
        $violations = $context->getValidator()->validate($this->number, $constraint);

        foreach ($violations as $violation) {
            $context->getViolations()->add($violation);
        }
    }
}
```

See https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html

> EDIT : I don't know what you're trying to validate so I just put some random params of your entity in there

Comment: I think this doesn't work because I need to check a field from the DB which I already have it in the controller!

Comment: If this field is on the same entity, then you should not need to fetch it from the DB. If it's in another entity, then you _must_ make a DB call anyway ...

Comment: No it's not in the same entity unfortunately, that's the issue I am trying to do this without a DB call :/

Comment: Well, your data is in the DB, so you cannot just magically pop it out of thin air. Either fetch it when displaying the form and add it to the form as a hidden field in the entity you're validating (and use the callback constraint with a payload), or fetch it after the submit and validate against it.

Comment: I mentioned in the question that I am not using the FormType, and I have the DB entity already In the Controller and that's why I wanted to know If someone knows any different way to add a specific validation in the Entity :)